# paracol and memoir/pedersen don't play nice

Tags: memoir, incompatibility

I am having a problem using `paracol` and `memoir`/`pedersen` together. As you can see from the minimal example, the second chapter number runs off to the other side.

This is a LyX file.

```
% Preview source code
 
%% LyX 2.0.0 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{memoir}
\usepackage{bookman}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{cmbr}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\pagestyle{ruled}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage[xetex]{color}
\definecolor{page_backgroundcolor}{rgb}{0.8515625, 0.953125, 1}
\pagecolor{page_backgroundcolor}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=section,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={This is my title},
 pdfauthor={dav},
 pdfsubject={adv},
 pdfkeywords={adv},
 xetex}
 
\makeatletter
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
 
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{paracol} %makes double columns
\columnsep10mm %separation between columns, e.g. for paracol
 
 
\@ifundefined{definecolor}
 {\usepackage{color}}{}
\definecolor{ared}{rgb}{.647,.129,.149}
\renewcommand{\colorchapnum}{\color{ared}}
\renewcommand{\colorchaptitle}{\color{ared}}
\chapterstyle{pedersen}
 
 
 
%Go to Document->Settings->LaTeX Preamble and add the following entries:
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[no-logos]{xltxtra} %provides xetex logo and other extras
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text} %fixes quotes dashes etc
 
\makeatother
 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\begin{document}
 
\chapter{First Chapter}
 
This is all random text. see below for paracol text.
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
 
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
 
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
 
 
\chapter{Second Chapter}
 
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
\noindent \begin{paracol}{2}$\begin{aligned}uu= & 1\end{aligned}
$
 
\noindent \switchcolumn
 
\noindent basic equation
 
\noindent \switchcolumn*$\begin{alignedat}{1}(uu)u= & 1\cdot u\end{alignedat}
$
 
\noindent \switchcolumn
 
\noindent multiply both sides on the right by $u$ (external)
 
\noindent \switchcolumn* $u(uu)=u$
 
\noindent \switchcolumn
 
\noindent association (internal)
 
\noindent \switchcolumn* $u(uu)=u$
 
\noindent \switchcolumn
 
\noindent substitution (internal)
 
\noindent \end{paracol}
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
 
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
 
Primo itaque homini, qui in eo bono quo factus fuerat 397 rectus acceperat
posse non peccare, posse non mori, posse ipsum bonum 398 non deserere,
datum est adiutorium perseverantiae, non quo fieret ut 399 perseveraret,
sed sine quo per liberum arbitrium perseverare non 400 posset. Nunc
vero sanctis in regnum Dei per gratiam Dei praedestinatis 401 non
tale adiutorium perseverantiae datur, sed tale ut eis perseverantia
402 ipsa donetur; non solum ut sine isto dono perseverantes esse non
403 possint, verum etiam ut per hoc donum non nisi perseverantes sunt.\}
404
 
Dem ersten Menschen, der in dem Gute, worin er gerecht 405 erschaffen
war, die F\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahigkeit empfangen hatte,
nicht zu s\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}undigen, 406 nicht zu sterben
und vom Guten selbst nicht ab\textbackslash{}-zufallen, ist demnach
407 die Gnade der Beharrlichkeit verliehen worden, nicht jene, wo\textbackslash{}-durch
408 seine Beharrlichkeit bewirkt worden w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
sondern jene, ohne die er 409 nicht imstande gewesen w\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}are,
mit seinem freien Willen auszuharren. 410 Jetzt aber wird den Heiligen,
die durch die Gnade Gottes f\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ur das
Reich 411 Gottes vorher\textbackslash{}-bestimmt sind, nicht eine
solche Gnade der Beharrlichkeit 412 gegeben, sondern eine derartige,
da\textbackslash{}ss\textbackslash{} ihnen die Beharrlichkeit selbst
413 geschenkt wird; daher sind sie ohne dieses Gnadengeschenk nicht
nur 414 unf\textbackslash{}\textquotedbl{}ahig zur Beharrlichkeit,
sondern sind auch durch dieses Geschenk 415 Nurbeharrende.
\end{document}
```

---

Not sure how I found it originally, but this is the author's site:

http://www.para.media.kyoto-u.ac.jp/latex/.

It produces side by side paragraphs like [`ledpar`](http://www.djdekker.net/ledmac/#alter) but simpler. There is also [parallel](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-parallel).

I hesitate to contact the author directly, since am still making sure where the problem is actually coming from....which may be `pedersen`.

Here is [a pdf file I created](http://contrakyoto.byethost9.com/SimpleTemplate.1.pdf) that shows the error.

Yes, true I did post there and [tug texhax](http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2011-September/018082.html).

If that is bad etiquette i.e. if these are considered part of the same system, apologies. I have added a note to that effect on those sites.

Comment: Same question in c.t.t: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/aa11fb671523f882#

Comment: Where did you get `paracol.sty`? I couldn't find it on CTAN.

Comment: the author of paracol.sty has agreed to get it to ctan "soon".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are far better ways of obtaining the desired output that does not require using [`paracol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/paracol). Since you already load [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath), I suggest you take advantage of the rich formatting capabilities provided by it, rather than resort to something else.

In the following code-snippet, which should replace your entire `paracol` usage, an `align*` environment produces a consistent layout:

[image]

```
%...
\begin{align*}
  uu    &= 1 && \text{basic equation} \\
  (uu)u &= 1\cdot u && \text{multiply both sides on the right by $u$ (external)} \\
  u(uu) &= u && \text{association (internal)} \\
  u(uu) &= u && \text{substitution (internal)}
\end{align*}
%...
```

Compare this to your original `paracol`-based Chapter 2 output and source:

[image]

```
%...
\noindent \begin{paracol}{2}$\begin{aligned}uu= & 1\end{aligned}
$

\noindent \switchcolumn

\noindent basic equation

\noindent \switchcolumn*$\begin{alignedat}{1}(uu)u= & 1\cdot u\end{alignedat}
$

\noindent \switchcolumn

\noindent multiply both sides on the right by $u$ (external)

\noindent \switchcolumn* $u(uu)=u$

\noindent \switchcolumn

\noindent association (internal)

\noindent \switchcolumn* $u(uu)=u$

\noindent \switchcolumn

\noindent substitution (internal)

\noindent \end{paracol}
%...
```

---

I did not modify the LyX file source code, which obviously contains hard-coded line numbers and incorrectly formatted accents.

Comment: Just wanted to belatedly say thank you for your time in answering this. I agree your version looks nicer. Yes, I could have been a little neater about the cut 'n paste lorem ipsum :-)